# Catching Click() in fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

**Js code**

```
    $(".iframe").fancybox({'zoomSpeedIn':   0, 'zoomSpeedOut':  0,  'showCloseButton'       : 'false','overlayShow':    false, 
"width" : 500,   "height" : 265 , 'titleShow': false,   'onClosed': function() {
parent.location.reload(true); }});  

 $("#abtn_add_new").click(function () {    alert("TEST!!!");   });
```

**And html**

```
<a  id="abtn_add_new" onclick=""><input  id="btn_add_new" type="image" src="/img/btn_add.png"/></a>
```

It doesn't work. Who knows what is problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$("#abtn_add_new").live('click', function () {    alert("TEST!!!");   });
```

Comment: That's because your jQuery says ".abtn_add_new" instead of "#abtn_add_new" ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture the click before fancybox loads the content you could use:

```
$("#abtn_add_new").fancybox({
 onStart: function() {
    alert('foobar')
 }
});
```